# sbt checkPgpSignatures

Tags: scala, sbt

I installed `addSbtPlugin("com.jsuereth" % "sbt-pgp" % "1.1.0")` in `project/plugins.sbt` but when I execute `sbt checkPgpSignatures` I get the following error:

```
[error] (updatePgpSignatures) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add artifact 'ciris-test_2.12.pom' to configuration 'pom' of module default#ciris-test_2.12;8d273508c294b5d224c7e0cb5ab00b7fa745fee8-SNAPSHOT because this configuration doesn't exist!
```

Anyone has an idea what could be wrong?